# Manipulating an object

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, beanshell

I have an object which looks like this.

```js
{
   "A": [ "1", "2", "3" ]
}
```

I want to manipulate the object to get the following result:

```js
{
    "A": [{
        "A": "1"
    }, {
        "A": "2"
    }, {
        "A": "3"
   }]
}
```

What is the way to achieve this?

Comment: Just FYI what you have is an object - it has absolutely nothing to do with JSON in this case. I've amended your question to cover that fact.

Comment: The way to achieve this is to write code. What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

As @MelanciaUK has mentioned, you will have to write code. There isn't just such a convert method you will have to call.

The following example will work in your usecase.

```
var myObj = {
   "A": [ "1", "2", "3" ]
}

//convert it
myObj = {
    "A": [{
        "A": "1"
    }, {
        "A": "2"
    }, {
        "A": "3"
   }]
}

//print result
console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how to convert that,

```
var myObj = {
   "A": [ "1", "2", "3" ]
} // this is the object you want to convert

var newObj = {}; //create a new empty object

newObj.A = [];// set a Key "A" of newObj to an empty Array.

for (i = 0; i < myObj.A.length; i++) //loop through the initial object and convert it
    {

     newobj.A[i] = {"A":myObj.A[i]} //for every iteration, add an object to the empty array.(newObj.A)
};
```